# Installing jogl from yaourt is trying to access jogamp.org

Tags: jogl, scilab, manjaro

So I am trying to install scilab in manjaro and I am trying to use yaourt, one of its requested packages is jogl-all-v2.3.2.jar.

When is downloading the file it stays like that:

```
  -> Found jogl.LICENSE.txt

  -> Found gluegen.LICENSE.txt

  -> Downloading jogl-all-v2.3.2.jar...

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:03 --:--:--     0
```

After some secconds it just stop, for time out.
I'm new in this and don't really know how to edit the "pkgbuild" file to make it work, or how to install an alternative version of the necessary software, but I hope I find some help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be patient. jogamp.org is currently down, there is a problem with our server.

Comment: I Just found a archive of the 2.3.2 version, then I changed the pkgbuild downloaded from yaourt to match the thing (links and md5 keys), and then I installed
I will be constanlly checking the site to see if it is online, and update right when it be.

Comment: jogamp.org is up :)